# Need my div to stay when inside my div is clicked

Tags: html, css

I found a code to show and hide content. It is a very easy code but the content disappears even if you click on the content in the box. There is no js just CSS. Please help me fix this problem.

```css
.span3:focus~.alert {
  display: none;
}

.span2:focus~.alert {
  display: block;
}

.alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="span3" tabindex="0">Hide Me</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
<p class="alert">Some alarming information here</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `focus`/`hover` state to the alert also:

```css
.span3:focus~.alert {
  display: none;
}

.span2:focus~.alert {
  display: block;
}

.alert {
  display: none;
  outline: none;
}

.alert:focus,
.alert:hover /*the hover is mandatory in this case*/{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="span3" tabindex="0" >Hide Me</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
<p class="alert" tabindex="0">Some alarming information here</p>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep the alert always visible until you click on hide me, you can try this:

```css
.span3 {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1; /*Make it above the alert*/
}

.span3:focus~.alert {
  display: none;
}

.span2:focus~.alert {
  display: block;
}

.alert {
  display: none;
  outline: none;
}

.alert:focus,
.alert:hover /*Here the hover is mandatory*/{
  display: block;
}

/*Cover the whole screen and keep the hover on the alert*/
.alert:after {
  content:"";
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<span class="span3" tabindex="0" >Hide Me</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
<p class="alert" tabindex="0">Some alarming information here</p>
```

Comment: @temaini thanks for simple and quick solution , but i also want when some click outside the box div will be still there , only hide when click on hide link

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to click on the div and rather not pass on it? In this case, hover can be a good solution. Look at that code:

Demo here

```css
.span3:focus ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}
.span2:focus ~ .alert {
  display: block;
}

.alert {
  display: none;
}

.alert:hover {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="span3" tabindex="0">Hide Me</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
<p class="alert" >Some alarming information here</p>
```

Have a good day.